# Laravel date cast

Tags: php, laravel, casting, php-carbon, accessor

Hello Every I want to use Laravel default casts feature, where if I access created_at property of a post model. I would like the following output from the following code:

Code:

```
$timepassed = $post->created_at;
```

Desired Output:

```
2 hours ago
```

The [laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators) provides only one example of casts for date which is :

```
protected $casts = [
'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
];
```

So when I access $post->created_at, the above casts will output "2023-06-20".

My question is what should I use instead of 'datetime:Y-m-d' to get output like: "2 hours ago"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Carbon library.

```
composer require nesbot/carbon
```

**Model**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

class Post extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->diffForHumans();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to make use of the [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) instead of using casts.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the created at value.
     *
     * @param  Carbon  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value->diffForHumans();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired output, you can specify a `create_at` attribute cast on your post model.

make sure you have the Carbon library installed in your Laravel project. You can install it by running the following command:

```
composer require nesbot/carbon
```

Attribute cast on your post model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

With this cast defined, accessing the `created_at` property will return an instance of Carbon, allowing you to format it as needed. To get the "2 hours ago" format, you can use the `diffForHumans()` method provided by Carbon.

Example:

```
$post = Post::find(1);
$post->created_at->diffForHumans();
```